# Action cable, ReactJS update fails Capybara spec

Tags: reactjs, capybara, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I'm testing a Rails 5 which uses action cable for almost every request. The UI uses reactjs components which are updated using JSON objects.

When I write a test to update a list, it fails to assert it is updated vissually, even though I can assert the database has been updated. If I test it manually (click test) everything works OK.

Here's my code sample:

https://github.com/instatodo/instatodo/blob/master/spec/features/todos_spec.rb

describe "Update task completed state" do
    before { visit todo_path(todo_with_tasks) }

```
it "modifies task state" do
  within first(".task") do
    find(".task-completed").click
    sleep 1
    expect(page).to have_checked_field(".task-completed") # This fails
  end
  expect(Task.where(completed: true)).not_to be_nil # This passes
end
```

end

And the react component:

https://github.com/instatodo/instatodo/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/components/task.jsx

Any ideas of why this isn't working?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`have_checked_field` takes the id, name, or associated label text of a checkbox element - it doesn't take a CSS selector.  If you don't have an id, name, or label text to use and only have one item with the `task-completed` class then you should be able to rewrite your expectation as

```
expect(page).to have_css('.task-completed:checked')
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Tom! This worked perfectly